# Rest-Assured. HTML. Response.prettyPrint() returns wrong data

Tags: java, html, css, rest-assured, pretty-print

[HTML sample link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FURRL6Q91QTN)

I make a GET request that return me a response with a sample of HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            <!-- SCROLL TOP BUTTON -->
            <!--===================================================-->
            <button id="scroll-top" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> 
            </button>
            <!--===================================================-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, there is NO attribute such as "type='submit'".

1. Then if you run next code:

```
given().body("{\"fileid\":\"FURRL6Q91QTN\"}")
                    .post("https://tryit.w3schools.com/code_datas.php")
                    .prettyPrint();
```

you'll see, that response body has button with type="submit":

```
<html lang="en">
  <head/>
  <body>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="scroll-top">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"/>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. And if you will try to validate rest-assured response body like this:

```
given().body("{\"fileid\":\"FURRL6Q91QTN\"}")
                .post("https://tryit.w3schools.com/code_datas.php")
                .then()
                .body("**.findAll{it.@id == 'scroll-top' && it.@type =='submit'}.size()", Matchers.is(0));
```

you'll see assertion fail message:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
>
> XML path **.findAll{it.@id == 'scroll-top' && it.@type == 'submit'}.size() doesn't match.
>
> Expected: is <0>
>
> Actual: 1

3. But if just print body response using asString() method before:

```
String responseStr = given().body("{\"fileid\":\"FURRL6Q91QTN\"}")
                .post("https://tryit.w3schools.com/code_datas.php")
                .asString();
System.out.println(responseStr);
```

the code will be fine and there will not be any type on that button:
[image: Pic]

=================================

**Question: what happens in 1-2 cases?**

Comment: Please try to explain your problem without images.

Comment: I'd really like to try to help here but screenshots make it pretty hard to read and decipher whats going on here. Can you post the actual code and actual text errors that you're receiving with explanations?

Comment: I've just changed the description. I hope that this time it will be more understandable :-)